# How to detect duplicate endpoints being exposed using rest?

Tags: rest, api, jersey

We are using Jersey implementation for exposing APIs. But sometimes we are exposing same URIs for different APIs.

Eg - http://localhost:8080/getUsernames - API1
     http://localhost:8080/getUsernames - API2

During deployment, we want to detect if the same URI is getting registered more than once, and if that is the case, we want to throw an exception.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks
Srumith